# What does "ruminoir" mean?

Tags: sens

> "Je voudrais, me dit Patachou, le (l'agneaux) faire bâiller."
>  "Et
> pourqui donc?"
>  "Parce que, s'il avait ouvert la bouche bien
> grande, j'aurais peut-être vu son **ruminoir**."
>  "Son
> **ruminoir**? "

This is from "Patachou" by Tristan Derême.
I can't understand the meaning of *ruminor*.
I am glad if someone would kindly teach me.

Comment: "Ruminoir" suggests "ruminant" or "ruminer," so presumably it refers to the sheep's digestive system in some capacity? There no dictionary entry for it and I don't have access to the text of "Patachou," so that is all that I have to go upon. But from the results of my web searches, it seems that there is a nuance that I am missing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It is hard to understand the meaning for non-native reader.

Answer (score 6):

@Maroon got it right in her comment.

***Ruminoir*** is listed in no dictionary but immediately evoques the verb ***ruminer*** to native ears.

*Ruminer* means to ruminate and can also be used figuratively to mean "to dwell on something", i.e. instead of bringing back food to chew it like cows of sheep, bringing back thoughts in the mind again and again.

Despite having no "legal" existence, ***ruminoir*** appears sporadically and means "the place where rumination occurs".

In your quote, the sense is literal: its rumen, its gullet.

A figurative meaning is more often observed, either a place where someone is alone and dwell on things, as @Laurent S. suggested, it is close to *boudoir* but pejorative, or, more rarely, a period of time when someone didn't act a lot, a *traversée du désert* (a barren spell).

Comment: I never heard these figurative meanings used. I guess the first one is to link with "boudoir", the second one is completely new to me.

Comment: @LaurentS.Le Parisien in 2011 about François Bayrou: *Cinq années de « ruminoir » Disant avoir beaucoup appris de ces cinq dernières années de solitude qu'il appelle « le ruminoir », on sent que le 3e homme de la présidentielle de 2007 a changé son fusil d'épaule.*